# Express rest api working in postman and development, but not when deployed

Tags: node.js, api, rest, express, deployment

I have a project with Vue frontend, Express backend and Mysql as database (using Sequelize as ORM)
In development, the frontend communicates with the backend API without any issues.
When backend deployed on heroku, i can get a valid response when i use postman to query the endpoints
but when i try to do the same from the frontend running on localhost:8080, i get a blocked error as shown in the screenshot
[image]

below is my server.js (express startup code) that works when hosted on localhost:5000 and can communicate with the frontend on localhost:8080 but when backend is deployed to heroku, also working through postman, the fontend can't access the API on heroku because it gets blocked

I dont know if this is a CORS issue as the error says nothing about CORS.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
//routes
const apiRouter = require('./routes/apiRouter');

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

/* -------------------------
Middlewares
------------------------
*/
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
/* Port and start up */
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: When deployed what ip are frontend and backend are on

Comment: frontend is not deployed, still runs on localhost:8080
backend deployed on heroku at https://getcvng.herokuapp.com/api/

Comment: Could you add the error you are getting also

Comment: I just figured out the issue, My timeout was 50ms, which worked find in development, but in production, it takes a while to get a response, i just increased the timeout for each request using an interceptor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axios timeout was too short to work in production.
it was set to 50ms. Just had to increase it to 5s using interceptors

```
//from api.js
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../store/store';
const token = store.getters.GET_WEBTOKEN;
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: store.state.apiURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: token,
  },
});


//in main.js
import api from './service/api';
Vue.prototype.$http = api;
api.defaults.timeout = 1000 * 5; //I changed this
```

Now i solved the issue, unto other oones